# Problems with select onchange getting input properly to trigger a function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have a form with dropdown; and when you select an `option` from list it triggers a function to load stuff on the page.

Basically I have a variable `$div_id` which is a number for each division.

What I am trying to do is have the "select" part of the drop down; have `on change` which triggers the function with the `$div_id` as input to the function.

The options for the dropdown are pulled in from a database.

So this is not working; and I am thinking the problem is the second line in this code, the `<select>` tag.  It is triggering the function - but it is not getting the input from the options;  (each `option` when you select it should send a different `div_id` to the function)

But somehow I think I am doing something wrong and I am not coding this right so the `div_id` can be inputted properly to the function.

here is my code:

```
<form>
    <select name="div_id" id="div_id" onchange="MyRadFunction('div_id')">
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM divisions";
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $resultsg1)
        { 
            $div_id = $resultsg1[div_id];
            $div_name = $resultsg1[div_name];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $div_id; ?>"  >
            <?php echo $div_name; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>

<!--  ***********  added function  -->

<script>

 function MyRadFunction(DivId) {
 var answer = DivId;
 $.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'mysite.com/gscript5_links.php',
   data: 'answer=' + answer,
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function(response) {
    $('#ajax_content').html(response);
   }
  });

    }
```

****************  UPDATE 10/17 2:06pm EST  ******************
to figure this out (with Regent's help) I had to basically get rid of everything that i had and just start from the beginning and then add things back one at a time to get this all to work; i am sure this is not the most elegant code but here is the code that worked:

```
<select id="comboA" onchange="G_function1(this)">

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM divisions";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $resultsg1)
{

 $div_id = $resultsg1[div_id];
 $div_name = $resultsg1[div_name];

 ?>

 <option value="<?php echo $div_id; ?>"  >

 <?php echo $div_name; ?></option>

 <?php   } ?>

</select>

<script>

 function G_function1(sel) {
 var value = sel.value;  
 var answer = value;
$.ajax({
cache: false,
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://jba.gtdsites.com/gscript5_links.php',
data: 'answer=' + answer,
dataType: 'html',
success: function(response) {
    $('#ajax_content').html(response);
}
});

    }
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js">       </script>

<div id="ajax_content" id="id57512">
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to send `<select>` ID by ajax, then you can use `onchange="MyRadFunction(this)"` and `function MyRadFunction(element) { var answer = element.id;`

Comment: Hello Regent:  thanks for providing that; it worked partially; but something weird is happening; the Onchange part doesn't seem to be working; furthermore; it seems to be getting all the div ids somehow; I need to do some testing on this...

Comment: I have already said that you should provide rendered HTML. If you have several `<select>`s, their HTML code should also be in question.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know what you mean by "rendered HTML"...

Comment: HTML code of page that browser "sees". Without any PHP - just formed/generated HTML.

Comment: Hello Regent:  thanks for all of your input on this.  Your comments helped me to figure this out.  I had to basically start over and just build it one step at a time.  If you want to see my new code just let me know and I will add it to the question.  But anyway thanks so much!

Comment: I take that back, I will just post it anyway...